# using ajax context does not resolve scope issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, scope

I am unable to make ajax context work:-

```
var msgdata = "";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "players/" + joinplayer + "/joingame.php",
  data: { 
    userID: "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>",
    gameinfo: JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['profile']['user'], true); ?>)
  },
  context: msgdata,
  success: function(data) {
    msgdata = data;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "renamejoin.php",
      data: { 
        userID: "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>",
        joinID: joinplayer
      },
      context: msgdata,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == "" && msgdata != "") {
          // sucessfully joined a player's game
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
      },
      error: function() {   
        alert(joinplayer + "'s game is no longer available.");
      }
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    alert(joinplayer + "'s game is no longer available.");
  }
});
if (msgdata == "");
  // start showing games awaiting players again
  gamefeedrefresh;
  timer = window.setInterval(gamefeedrefresh, 2500);
}
```

msgdata is always "" in this final if statement.  The problem seems to be a scope issue but even one or both of the context statements make no difference.

Is it possible to resolve this scope issue? All advice appreciated.

Comment: context needs to be an OBJECT, not a primitive - see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax requests are asynchronous, meaning the rest of your program will execute before the request comes back. If you want to run code after the request has been completed, move it into the `success` function body.

You may also want to have a look at [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Good points. I will check them out tomorrow as I have a crisis today :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force browser to finish execute first the request before continue reading the script, you just add `async` option in your ajax method and set it to `false`.

```
async: false
```

Comment: bad advice as synchronous xmlhttprequests on the main thread are deprecated :p

Comment: Useful for interim solution perhaps, while I figure out the async way to do it correctly. This is also helpful to see what the asynchronous version will require.

Comment: I was unable to get `async: false` to work in this situation :-(

Answer (score 0):

The overall solution wasn't too complex once the asynchonosity was taken into consideration.

The main issue was to make a function for the error exits
then waiting for the second success to be triggered
to use the msgdata from the first ajax call,
which was always in scope but only valid
on the second ajax's successful trigger.

The joinfailed function could be inline so that joinplayer would still be in scope but I couldn't decide which error exit to put it on so I decided to keep it separate.

```
$("#gamefeed").on('click', ".chooseGame", function (evnt) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "players/" + joinplayer + "/joingame.php",
    data: { 
      userID: "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>",
      gameinfo: JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['profile']['user'], true); ?>)
    },
    success: function(data) {
      msgdata = data;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "renamejoin.php",
        data: { 
          userID: "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>",
          joinID: joinplayer
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data != "") {
            joinfailed(joinplayer);
          } else {
            alert(msgdata); // "you joined joinplayer's game"
            // initialise comms and join the game
          }
        },
        error: function() {   
          joinfailed(joinplayer);
        }
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      joinfailed(joinplayer);
    }
  });
});
function joinfailed(joinplayer) {
  alert(joinplayer + "'s game is no longer available.");
  // start showing games awaiting players again
  gamefeedrefresh;
  timer = window.setInterval(gamefeedrefresh, 2500);
}
```